Unexpected behavior with EntityManager and the Persistence Context
I am currently trying to learn both JPA and Hibernate and I've been playing around with some dummy code to understand how everything works. However, I've come up with an example that I don't quite understand. This is the code:
Given the following entity definition (just a dummy one for the example):
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    private String name;  
    private String address;  

    ...getters and setters

And the following code:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
    options.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    options.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");

    EntityManagerFactory emf = new HibernatePersistenceProvider()
        .createContainerEntityManagerFactory(new CustomPersistenceUnitInfo(), options);
    
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        
        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.setId(1);

        em.persist(e);
        em.remove(e);

        
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}

Let's also imagine the the table "employees" already has a row with id = 1.
This is what i was expecting that happened: an entity of Employee called "e" will be created (transient state). After the persist call the entity will be added to the context, changing its state to managed. After the remove call, the entity state will change to "removed", that means that by the time the commit happens the only operation that should be mirrored to the database is the delete one, because we only have one entity in the context with the removed state. The insert should not happen because i didn't manually flush after the persist call and as the documentation says, unflushed changes will be lost.
However, after i execute the code, i can see that an insert is happening:
Hibernate: insert into employees (address,name,id) values (?,?,?).

And this will throw an exception because an entry with id "1" already exists in the database. Why is an insert happening? Shouldn't just the remove operation be propagated to the database? Is my mental model about the context wrong?
I know that in the real world it wouldn't make sense to persist something that already exists (merge should be called instead) or persist without flushing the changes, but i am just trying to understand how everything works underneath :D.

The documentation for EntityManager.persist(Object) states that it makes "an instance managed and persistent" (emphasis mine). And that is what you are observing. The entity manager doesn't know about the instance in the database and hence is persisting what was provided to it.

But that state is being overwritten by the remove call, going from "managed and persistent" to "removed". So, by the time the transaction commits (which is when the context mirrors the state to the database), we should only have that state right?

But EntityManager documentation says "A persistence context is a set of entity instances in which for any persistent entity identity there is a unique entity instance.". But by providing an instance to persist that does not represent the row in the database you have violated this and the entity manager is required to report this violation via the exception.

But the persistence context should not be aware of the database state until flush happens right? What i don't understand is why an insert query is being sent to the database, when the state of the Entity is "removed" (last call before transaction commit). The persist call only makes the entity persistent and managed, but that's overwritten by the last call.

But the entity manager is unable to ensure anything without knowing whether the entity exists in the database when you are manually setting ids. Try you code with a generated id. Then you probably will observe what you expect.

It acts the same way, it triggers both insert + delete.

To avoid the call to the database, you would need to call evict() to remove the entity from the persistence context, as if hibernate/jpa had never seen it.
Anyway, you would use an IdGenerator in real life, to avoid clashes.
